# Shell script with infinite loop: kill subprocess

Tags: shell

I have a question. I want to run a start and stop script via the webbrowser on my raspberry pi (only in local network). So I made two scripts, whick will be run from my website through php. This works very well. But the two scripts are my problem:

First script is the start script:

```
#!/bin/bash
while true; do
  wget http://... -O /dev/null
  sleep 1
done
```

And the stop script:

```
#!/bin/bash
kill $(pgrep start.sh)
```

The problem is, that if I kill the start script, wget will not be killed. Normaly I would solve this problem with writing the wget pid to /tmp. But for that I need to run wget with the `&` and many wget processes will be start.
An easy solution might be adding `killall wget` to the stop script, but if there is another wget running, that might be not the best idea.

Comment: Why does killing `wget` bother your? If will die eventually, as soon as it will complete (either normally or with timeout).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Because if I will do updates and the script is running in background I might get an update error. Both at the first try I will launch the script only manually, so this won't be an big issue at the moment.

Comment: Your `wget` invocation doesn't change any state, it doesn't write anything to a file, etc. Because of that, I don't really see any way it could influence the other system, besides of consuming some resources (which I hardly could expect to bother you).